# Div background color, to change onhover slowly

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to make a div's background color change on mouse over. I wanna make background like [this spnashot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KPIi1.png)

and i am using this code on hover. I also wanna that when mouse over then color will change slowly

```css
.header_col a:hover{
  background: -webkit-repeating-linear-gradient(#74ABDD, #74ABDD 49.9%, #498DCB 50.1%, #498DCB 100%);
  background: -o-repeating-linear-gradient(#74ABDD, #74ABDD 49.9%, #498DCB 50.1%, #498DCB 100%);
  background: -moz-repeating-linear-gradient(#74ABDD, #74ABDD 49.9%, #498DCB 50.1%, #498DCB 100%);
  background: repeating-linear-gradient(#74ABDD, #74ABDD 49.9%, #498DCB 50.1%, #498DCB 100%); 
  color: white!important;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hope this code will work

```css
.header_col li {
  display:inline-block;
  transition: background 0.2s;
  transform: skew(20deg);  /* SKEW */

}
.header_col li a {
  display:block;
  text-decoration:none;
  color: black!important;
  transform: skew(-20deg); /* INVERSE SKEW */

}
.header_col li:hover{
  background: -webkit-repeating-linear-gradient(#74ABDD, #74ABDD 49.9%, #498DCB 50.1%, #498DCB 100%);
  background: -o-repeating-linear-gradient(#74ABDD, #74ABDD 49.9%, #498DCB 50.1%, #498DCB 100%);
  background: -moz-repeating-linear-gradient(#74ABDD, #74ABDD 49.9%, #498DCB 50.1%, #498DCB 100%);
  background: repeating-linear-gradient(#74ABDD, #74ABDD 49.9%, #498DCB 50.1%, #498DCB 100%); 
  color: white!important;
}
.header_col li a:hover{
   color: white!important;
}
```

```html
<ul class="header_col">
 <li><a href="#">Page 1</a></li>
 <li><a href="#">Page 2</a></li> 
 <li><a href="#">Page 3</a></li> 
 <li><a href="#">Page 4</a></li>
 <li><a href="#">Page 5</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: but where is the slowly change ? this was the purpose no ?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need gradients for that, check this example:

**Edit:** Now works with text.

```css
    .button {
        position: relative;
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        top: 0;
        z-index: -1;
        transform: skewX(30deg);
    }

    .button::after {
        content: "";
        position: absolute;
        bottom: 0;
        width: 100%;
        height: 50%;
        background-color: rgba(63, 142, 191,1);
    }

    .button::before {
        content: "";
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
        width: 100%;
        height: 50%;
        background-color: rgba(63, 142, 191,1);
        transition: all .7s;
    }

    .wrapper:hover .button:before {
        background-color: rgba(63, 142, 191, .5);
    }

    a {
        text-align: center;
        width: 100%;
        left: 0;
        right: 0;
        height: 100%;
        width: 100%;
        position: absolute;
        margin: 0;   
        display:flex;
        justify-content: center;
        align-items: center;

    }

    .wrapper {
        position: absolute;
        width: 200px;
        height: 80px;
        z-index: 9;
        left: 0;
        right: 0;
        margin: auto;
    }
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">

    <a href="#">Text</a>

    <div class="button">
    </div>

</div>
```

Comment: Not working properly My code https://jsfiddle.net/1qvx8q4b/  on hover li is showing like this https://i.imgur.com/Zsawsue.png   but i wanna display like this  https://i.imgur.com/ek4fcQ0.png

Comment: @Temani Afif ok, but no need to downvote, I just forgot about the text. I updated the code.

Comment: Don't forget the purpose of the thing .. it's a clickable link and in your case it won't do the work, we need to have an **a** tag with text inside it. And downvoting isn't bad or personnal, it allow us to improve our answer/questions

Comment: @Temani Afif So what's the problem in changing html tag? How it won't work in my case? I don't understand you now...

Comment: now you change it to **a** and it's good ;) that's what am saying, the code need to be complete to avoid any confusion. I was just helping you to have a good solution. we are not in a competition, we just need to get the correct answer.

Answer (score -2):

To change the color on hover you may try like this

```
a{
    transition-duration: 0.8s;
    transition-delay: 0.5s;
    transition-property: color;
}
```

first, define these codes in "a" tag then give the hover effect
transition-property has defined the property you want to animate or move.